# Debugging deserialization of objects

Tags: java, deserialization

I am confused in something and hopefully you can clarify.

I would like to debug a deserialization task.
I have :

- a class that implements java.io.Serializable
- the class hass setters and getters.
- I am reading a stream from that class, which works except of a field:

  ```
          ois = new ObjectInputStream(bos);
          o=ois.readObject();
  ```

Now my general quetion :
Can't I just have some breakpoints in the getters and setters of the class to see what happens during readObject() ? . In my case it seems it will not go through my setters during readObject(), because my breakpoints are ignored.

So my general question is. Does the readobject task call the setters of the class or not ?

Comment: No, it doesn't. Here's how deserialization works: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/platform/serialization/spec/input.html

Comment: Do you have a hint, how can I debug the process, when I get a wrong value in a field after deserialization ?

Comment: Check what the field really was before serialization. That's where the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, standard Java serialization will never invoke getters or setters (not even the constructor, except for the first non-serializable super-class).

Unless you take control by writing your own private `readObject` method (or implementing `Externalizable`), `ObjectInputStream` will just read fields (except for `static` and `transient`) using *unsafe* magic and reflection.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.